# how to write a cloud-based Active directory .NET application

Tags: azure, active-directory

I work for a network management company and I want to write a .Net application (MVC 4) that will allow us to service Active Directory users from a cloud-based application.

As I have never written a cloud-based app, I don't know if I'm using that term correctly or not. I am in the requirements gathering stage.  Basically, I'd like to provide our customers with the ability, for example, to change their own password using our cloud-based application.

- is this an application that should be written specifically using Azure?  If not, what tools and platform(s) should I take into consideration?
- What tutorials or other resources are available ?

Actually, I don't even know enough about Active Directory and Cloud computing to ask the right questions.  But, I hope someone will point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Read [How to Authenticate Web Users with Windows Azure Active Directory Access Control](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/).  There are great walk-throughs there.  There is more reading and code samples here - [Access Control Service 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147631.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That's using ACS.

You could go direct to Azure Active Directory if you wished?

Refer: [Adding Sign-On to Your Web Application Using Windows Azure AD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151790.aspx).

If you use Office 365, you already have an AAD tenant.